# Followers on Area 51 proposal ad is different from actual followers

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

This is my area 51 proposal ad.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Mobile DevicesCell Phones]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/60741.png))</sub>

It shows 3 followers, but there are 5 followers.

What is the reason for the inconsistency?

Comment: Probably caching. No need to reload it all the time, just in case there is a new follower. BTW it shows 5 for me.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Really? . It shows 3 for me

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: -1, it says six followers. Nyah.

Comment: @Won't Thats for you. I had cache problems thats why it showed 3 but after following animuson's answer it shows correctly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All images served from Stack Exchange are very heavily cached so they don't have to be downloaded so often. That also includes flair images, which probably change more often than these Area 51 advertisements. Give it some time, your browser will eventually download a newer one (or you can clear your local cache to force an update if you want).